Type infrencing in Kotlin lists
I have 2 lists, one called mod:
listOf("Money", 1)
And one called splitSave which is a 113 item long list of strings.
I am trying to access the index of the splitSave list based on the one index of the first list. I tried to do it with this line: println("$mod[1]: ${splitSave[mod[1]]}") When compiling, I get a type mismatch error because mod[1]'s type is "any"
How can I explicitly define the type, or get Kotlin to inference it's type properly?
It should be able to find the proper index, although it errors out and stops the program.

You have a list that contains both a string and an int. So the list is neither a string list nor an int list. It's a list that contains anything. If you want type safety, you should use another type of structure here. Examples: use a pair : "Money" to 1, then you can access the money index using mod.second. Or you could use a Map: mapOf("Money", 1) accessed using mod["Money"], or an enum: enum class Mods(index: Int) { Money(1) } and use it like this: mod.index.

@amanin That would make a good answer!

Since mod contains both a String and an Int, its type will be inferred to be List<Any>. This is correct so there is nothing you can do about the type of the list. However, if you want to get the value contained at mod[1] and treat it as an Int, you can cast that value to an Int after you have retrieved it from the list as follows:
val splitSave = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
val mod = listOf("Money", 1)

val modIndex1 = mod[1] as Int

println("$modIndex1: ${splitSave[modIndex1]}")

Casting allows you to tell the compiler to treat that value as an Int and thus the type of modIndex1 will be Int. Do be aware, though, that if you attempt to cast a String to an Int, you will get a ClassCastException.

With this cast you give up the type safety otherwise guaranteed by the compiler. If, for whatever reason, mod[1] can not be cast to an Int, that error will only surface during runtime and crash your program. Therefore the suggestion of @amanin in the comments to refactor your list is better since it enables the compiler to guarantee that what you expect to be an Int actually is an Int, even later on at runtime.
